# Is 3.6 km drive, twice a day, enough for maintaining battery charged well? My car is a Toyota Corolla, 2014

Tags: battery

My car is Toyota Corolla, 2014, I only have two short drives each day, which is 3.6 km per way.

Comment: We used to suggest 10km minimum at decent speeds, crawling in traffic at tickover does not charge the battery very well, yes I know it puts the light out...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the nature of the drive as well as the distance but in general I would say that's insufficient in of itself. Not only for the battery but also for other elements of the car such as the emissions control features.

If possible give the car a lengthier run (at varying speed and load) once every couple of weeks.

**PS:** you don't mention fuel type, if its a diesel then that usage pattern would be insufficient to trigger Diesel Particulate Filter regenerations and you would need to do the appropriate procedure regularly or risk serious damage to the DPF

Comment: Thanks! However, I am a senior, and difficult to drive so lengthy. What would happen if I don’t be able to do so? By the way, my battery is new.

Comment: @Ying as Solar Mike suggests a battery tender/conditioner will keep on top of it, ideally you'd still want a longer run (~40 miles or so) every now and again for general health of the car but I appreciate that that's not always easy

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, based on your comment, is to use a battery tender or charger.

CTEK make them for one, but you will need access to a power supply.

If the battery charger is not an option, and you are in a sunny location and a solar panel will work, that may help. Smaller ones clamp to the roof but theft may be an issue...